# Restructuring Excel Spreadsheet Data

Tags: excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet with membership data, which includes each member’s coverage start date and coverage end date (if applicable) among many other data fields.  I’m trying to restructure the data so that each month that the member’s coverage was effective is represented by a single row.  For example, if a member has a coverage start date of 1/1/2019 and a coverage end date of 12/31/2019, the member’s information would be displayed 12 times.  If the member has no coverage end date listed, then the number of rows listed for that member will be based on the number of months between the coverage start date and a date defined by the user.

To further complicate the issue, there are instances within the data that a member is displayed more than once due to changes in various coverage options so the total number of rows for a particular member will need to represent all months in which their coverage was in effect.

Any ideas/suggestions as to how to accomplish all of this?

Comment: Index() with match() and you will probably need iferror().

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on your needs moving forwards.  Changing the data to a per-month format and maintaining it that way is different than continuing to maintain the original data, and also needing to convert it to this new format.  Consider that carefully when you choose how to do this.  You might make things more difficult for yourself moving forwards.

In order to convert the data you currently have (which I assume is one line per member) to the data you want (one line per month per member) I would write a VBA script which would loop through the entire first sheet and do the steps to get it in the format I want.  If you are not VBA saavy, you can do this with filters.  The steps for manual filtering would be:

- Find the earliest month you have (Let's say for this example that is January 2000), and filter your data for that month only.
- Copy the filtered lines only to a new sheet.  This is your January 2000 data.
- At this point, you can either modify the lines you just copied so they indicate they are January 2000, or name the page January 2000, and keep each month on its own page.
- Do the same for the next month.  Continue until you have all of your data sorted by month.

At this point, you can modify and recombine the data, or leave it in separate sheets.

For a VBA solution, I would go line by line through the original data, and copy the line to each location in belongs in based on start/end dates.  If separate sheets, I would pre-create all the sheets I need.

Good luck.